# Django 'none' values from ajax

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

My views:

```
def deleteDepartement(request):

  object_id = request.POST.get('Id')
  name= request.POST.get('name')

  print(object_id)
  print(name)
  try:
    D=Department.objects.get(id=object_id)
    
  except:
    print("NOT FOUND")
    
  return redirect('department')
```

JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST', 
  url: "{% url 'deleteDepartement' %}", 
  data: {
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
    Id:objectId,
    name:'test',
  },
});
```

I got none in value in django views. When I `console.log` I got the id, but when i try to sent it i got none. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.